# How to use animation listener for Lottie animation in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lottie

In Android View System, We can use animation listener like below to get lottie animation callbacks.

```
 playView = LottieAnimationView(this)
 playView.addAnimatorListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
           
        }

        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {
        }

        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {
        }
    })
```

How we can add listener using Jetpack Compose? i added below code currently to play the lottie animation. I want to receive the callback after animation play completed.

```
@Composable
fun PlayView() {
    val animationSpec = remember { LottieAnimationSpec.RawRes(R.raw.play_anim) }
    val result: LottieCompositionResult by remember { mutableStateOf(LottieCompositionResult.Loading) }
    val context = LocalContext.current
    LottieAnimation(
        animationSpec,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth()
    )

    if (result is LottieCompositionResult.Success) {
        //start the next flow
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Updated answer to version `1.0.0-rc01-1` of Lottie.**

What you can do is:

```kotlin
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(
    LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.your_lottie_file)
)
val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(composition)

LottieAnimation(
    composition,
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(200.dp)
        .background(Color.Black),
) 

if (progress == 1.0f) {
    // Animation completes.
}
```

Comment: Looks like in latest version, above code will not work. they have removed animationState parameter in LottiAnimation()

Comment: But as per the documentation, below callbacks available but did not see any sample code. https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/android-compose "Access error, isLoading, isComplete, isFailure, and isSuccess properties."

Comment: i guess they didnt implement some thing like `lottieProgressAsState`

Comment: ths, the code work in latest version right now. "progress" is a state, compose really will do it after animation finished.